# Declare a global when building an Angular library

Tags: angular, build, cesiumjs, angular-library

I posted the following on the AngularCesium github as an issue (because I figured they had some experience with this problem as they need "Cesium" in their scope too).

Since their Github is less active than I would have hoped for, I wanted to post it here too as this might speak to a broader design pattern I am unaware of with Angular library code.

---

I have been using this library [AngularCesium] for a good while now within an angular application with no problems. I recently have started pulling code out of that application to create a library so multiple applications in my company can use the same components and services. I am now having build issues, described below.

Disclaimer: this might not be an issue with the angular-cesium library, but I expect you're the correct people to raise this question to. Please direct me who you think I should address with this question if you don't think it fits here.

**Intended outcome:**
When I run `ng build <my_project>` I expect it to build properly and give me a consumable package I can publish to our internal package registry.

**Actual outcome:**
Instead, I get the following errors (all the same) for every instance I use the Cesium global.

```
projects/<my-company>/tm-cesium/src/services/trace-annotation.service.ts:185:21 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Cesium'.

185                     Cesium.JulianDate.compare(
                        ~~~~~~
```

I have a demo application within the same workspace (the Angular workspace is what contains the `projects/` directory) which I can successfully `ng serve` and run. All references to `Cesium` work. That demo app contains a `typing.d.ts` file as described in [your documentation](https://docs.angular-cesium.com/getting-started/installation), but I cannot determine how to declare a global that gets recognized the same way when compiling an angular library.

Similarly, I cannot include the following in the build configurations as these properties are not allowed in the build options for libraries, as they are in the build options for applications.

```
   "assets": [ // ...
     { "glob": "**/*", "input": "./node_modules/cesium/Build/Cesium", "output": "./assets/cesium" }
    ],
   "styles": [ // ...
     "./node_modules/cesium/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css"
   ],
   "scripts": [ // ...
     "./node_modules/cesium/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"
   ],
```

Really, the key to this seems like a question of how to go about doing the same thing we did with the `typing.d.ts` file for applications, but for my library. Everything else seems to work fine, if I could just get the compiler to respect that `Cesium` will exist at runtime.

**How to reproduce the issue:**
I cannot supply any source code but I can supply snippets of configuration files upon request.

The versions of the dependencies involved are here:

```
        "angular-cesium": "0.0.71",
        "cesium": "^1.70.1",
```

**Version**

- angular-cesium@0.0.71

Answer (score 1):

Face-palming a little bit now, I created an `index.d.ts` file and included in my `tsconfig.lib.json` the following line:

```
"typeRoots": ["./src/lib/typings"],
```

and it seems to be working. Looks like this is the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

One option you have would be to put a similar `typing.d.ts` file in the `src` of your library and then include it where you need using a [triple slash directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html)

`/// <reference path="../../typing.d.ts" />`

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will try this if the solution I posted above gives me trouble :)

Comment: Yeah, that solution's better, since it puts it all in one place.  With the triple slash directive, you'd have to have it on each file you need that on, which isn't ideal.